# PHP RestFul API with eCheck

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I'm currently testing a feature I see added to the PHP RestFul API with regards to accepting payments via eCheck. There is currently no documentation on Paypal's Developer website regarding this so I'm simply reading the API Code and figuring this out based on how I currently have a proper working Credit Card Transaction.

Whenever I post a transaction I'm receiving an internal error on Paypal API side:

```
Array
(
    [name] => INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
    [message] => An internal service error has occurred
    [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
    [debug_id] => 4a0a3d669966c
)
```

*Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment*

The error is very vague and offers no hints for a possible solution.

I've create a GIST so you can the code I am using, perhaps there is something I am missing here: [ChargeEcheck.php](https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/dd0a8fad684e2085b82d#file-chargeecheck-php-L140-L152)

If there is a problem with this code its gotta be between lines 140-152

I'm not receiving any other errors at all. The code to the Credit Card side of things is very similar as the code in that GIST and it works perfectly fine.

I've also looked at the developer dashboard and couldn't find anything that referenced any eCheck options to enable/disable.

Has anyone else had this issue using the PHP RestFul API's?

Some additional details I can provide:

Paypal Core SDK API Version 2.5.7

Paypal RestFul API Version 0.16.1

PHP 5.6.4

I'd be happy to supply any additional information too if needed.

Comment: Not a PHP dev. See [`funding_instrument`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#fundinginstrument-object) and [`Payer`-> `payment_method`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payer-object) definitions vs [lines 151-155](https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/dd0a8fad684e2085b82d#file-chargeecheck-php-L151-L155)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently REST API does not support eCheck. The only supported funding types are Credit Cards, and PayPal. However, the functionality is taken into consideration, and should be available, but there are no specific timeline available for public announcement.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why the API Code Comments say otherwise? For example in the Rest API SDK Api\Payer.php the comments clearly offer `Valid Values: ["credit_card", "bank", "paypal"]` for `setPaymentMethod()`. Also valid errors are returned when such things as `setBirthDate()` are not set on the `BankAccount` function.

Comment: There are few features that are developed, and being tested by very few specific merchants, before it is released outside to public developers. Our SDKs use automated system to generate those model classes from schema files that are developed internally. We are actually enhancing our SDK Generator to not include details like this, and try not to confuse external developers with comments like this. My apologies on this.